# When opening my camera it display black at first - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

When opening starting my camera function for my `ViewController` the screen appears black sometimes for a limited amount of time and I am not sure why?

Heres what I am doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self startCamera];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToHome" sender:self];
}
-(void)startCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController

                                             alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)

                               kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //UISaveVideoAtPath
    imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0f; // limits video length to 30 seconds.
    [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
    [imagePicker viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
}
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't told how much time it consume.

If it comes for some seconds then it's not an issue.
because camera needs to load first and then it will come for you to use the every functionality.
this is default thing happen every time.

You can check out this thing even in default camera app.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense because sometimes it comes and sometimes it takes a little.